# CSS background color not appearing

Tags: html, css

My webpage has a footer with 4 separate footer cols. They are separated by a 5px margin on the right and left side. They also have a green background. The Footer (containing element) has a red background but does not appear. I validated the HTML and could not find a problem with XHTML markup so I'm assuming it's a CSS woe.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/48dk6/

Footer CSS declarations.

```
/* footer and descendants */
#footer {
  font-size:1.3em;
  margin-top:10px;
  clear:both;
  background-color:red;
  }

/* footer col styling/positioning */
.footerCol {
  background-color:green;
  width:180px;
  float:left;
  margin:10px 5px 10px 5px;
  }
```

Comment: Because your `footerCol` are floating, make your `#footer` float and issue solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your `#footer` CSS:

```
#footer {
    font-size:1.3em;
    margin-top:10px;
    clear:both;
    background-color:red;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/48dk6/3/)**

This will restore the behavior you seek, which is caused by the children `.footerCol` divs being floated. Floating those child divs removes them from the normal flow, so the parent behaves as if there is nothing for it to contain.

Comment: Thanks, mind giving me a small explanation?. For what I know overflow handles elements that are larger than the containing element.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float#Clearing_floats. It has to do with the block formatting context created by the floats.

Answer (score 1):

Add overflow: auto; to #footer.

When you float items inside a block element you often want to use overflow: auto or else the enclosing element gets whacky and won't show up unless you specify a height and width (which you usually don't want to do)

```
#footer {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 10px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you should have a height set for your footer, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/48dk6/7/)

```
height:240px;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/48dk6/6/

Remove the floating and simply display the elements as inline-blocks

```
  .footerCol {
  background-color:green;
  width:180px;
  display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The containing floats problem can be solved with 2 approaches:

1. Adding something with `clear` after the floats (the most common solution is `clearfix` with clearing [pseudo element](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)).
2. Making the container create new [Block Formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context). The most popular ways are setting to the container `overflow:hidden/auto`, `display:table`, `display:inline-block` (+ width, if necessary), or floating the container itself.

All approaches have their advantages and limitations, so choose what fits better in your case.

There is [a proposal](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing/#the-contain-floats-value) to add `min-height:contain-floats` value to solve this, but it isn't supported by browsers yet.